# Meu cache está sendo compartilhado pelas paginas tem como deixa lo por sessão?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autenticação, cache

Bom dia galera,
então, criei uma class para tratar o cache , porem abrir o site no mesmo navegador mas com usuarios diferentes, um pega o cache do outro.
como eu posso restringir por "sessão" isso? Obrigado !

Metodos:

```
    public T GetKeyValue<T>(string key)
    {
        var cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
        if (cache != null)
            return (T)cache;

        return default(T);
    }

    public void SetKeyValue<T>(T obj, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) || obj == null)
            return;

        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, obj,
                        null,
                        DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration 
                        );
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Ao abrir mais uma aba, esse metodo sobrescreve o "user" assim todos os sites abertos pegam cores,estilos,configurações do user que tiver...
a minha duvida é, como fazer isso cache por usuario de uma forma correta, limpa etc. pq eu concatenei mas ainda sim as vezes quebra alguma coisinha

```
   public void Authenticate(string user)
    {
        if (CanAuthenticated(user))
        {
            this.User = user;
            this.Password = "password";
            var villaUser = this.SPAccessLogin.LogIn();
            this.VillaSiteUser = villaUser;
            this.IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: pode dar mais detalhes? Você está usando isso na controller? Usa WebApi? Você pode usar o sessionId e colocar na chave do seu cache, para separa o cache por usuário usando isso: `HttpContext.Session.SessionID`

Comment: Desculpe a demora, então, eu estou usando somente cache, atualmente eu estou concatenando o usuario(ex.: vinicius_WebApiPath) para diferenciar, mas isso foi provisorio, eu queria que o cache pegasse um valor que seja exclusivo daquela aba, pq o site em que eu trabalho ele pega o usuario pelo dominio

viniciusImobiliaria.com.br => usuario = viniciusImobiliaria
e apartir disso eu faço tudo oq eu tenho q fazer, pq é um template, cada usuario tem um site pra ele com o seu dominio. mas o sistema q verifica cores, estilos e etc...

Comment: Bem, o propósito do cache e otimizar alguma coisa que vai ser usada por vários usuários. Cache por usuário não faz sentido, isso deveria ser armazenado numa `Session`, que é o objeto próprio para isso. Mas você chegou a testar o `HttpContext.Session.SessionID` ?

Comment: as sessions fica carregada no pool do iis, então se eu tiver mil usuarios vou ter mil sessions. dai sim não faria sentido, pois eu ia acabar com meu servidor. e esse é o problema, ja temos problemas com sessions...